# Find a dictionary in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries named `tickets` and a single dictionary named `issue`. How do I find the dictionary in `tickets` such that `tickets[i]['summary'] == issue['title']`?

Comment: `next(t for t in tickets if t['summary'] == issue['title'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension like this

```
print [ticket for ticket in tickets if ticket['summary'] == issue['title']]
```

or you can use `filter` like this

```
print filter(lambda ticket: ticket["summary"] == issue["title"], tickets)
```

Timeit Results say that the list comprehension is faster than filter and generator methods

```
tickets = [{"summary" : "a"}, {"summary" : "a"}, {"summary" : "b"}]
issue = {"title" : "a"}
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("[ticket for ticket in tickets if ticket['summary'] == issue['title']]", setup="from __main__ import tickets, issue")
print timeit('filter(lambda ticket: ticket["summary"] == issue["title"], tickets)', setup="from __main__ import tickets, issue")
print timeit("list(ticket for ticket in tickets if ticket['summary'] == issue['title'])", setup="from __main__ import tickets, issue")
```

On my machine, I got

```
0.347553014755
0.691710948944
1.10066413879
```

Even if the objective is to get only one element which matches

```
tickets = [{"summary" : "a"}, {"summary" : "a"}, {"summary" : "b"}]
issue = {"title" : "a"}
setupString = "from __main__ import tickets, issue"
from timeit import timeit
print timeit("[ticket for ticket in tickets if ticket['summary'] == issue['title']][0]", setup=setupString)
print timeit('filter(lambda ticket: ticket["summary"] == issue["title"], tickets)[0]', setup=setupString)
print timeit("next(ticket for ticket in tickets if ticket['summary'] == issue['title'])", setup=setupString)
```

Output on my machine

```
0.369271993637
0.717815876007
0.557427883148
```

Comment: Your comment about the relative speeds isn't correct. Test lists with more than three elements.

Answer (score 1):

The long way, but this will search through the entire list:

```
for i in tickets:
   if i['summary'] == issue['title']:
      print('Found it!')
   else:
      print('Does not exist')
```

You can make it into a function, which will will return once your dictionary is found:

```
def search(k, n):
    for i in k:
       if i['summary'] == n['title']:
           return i

results = search(tickets, issue)
if not results:
   print('No matching ticket found')
```

Or, as @Blender suggested - use a generator:

```
result = next(t for t in tickets if t['summary'] == issue['title'])
```

Comment: This will print `Does not exist` for all the other tickets.

Answer (score 0):

Also, a functional variant:

```
filter (lambda dict: dict['summary'] == issue['title'], tickets)
```

will return all dictionaries with the condition.